# elastic 6.8 timeout error for some indexes

Tags: elasticsearch, timeout, elastic-stack

We have a standalone (one machine) elasticsearch node containing so much data. Recently, I noticed that for some of our indexes, elastic returns 504 Gateway Time-out error (shown below) even for a simple query (get n latest indexes). I checked the log and found nothing suspecious. Ho Can I find out what is causing this time out? It works perfectly for other indexes. Can it be because of only one node and low resources?

```
GET the_index/_search
{
   "query": {
   "match_all": {}
   },
   "size": 10,
   "sort": [
   {
      "timestamp": {
      "order": "desc"
      }
   }
   ]
}
```

elastic Results:

```
{
    "statusCode": 504,
    "error": "Gateway Time-out",
    "message": "Client request timeout"
}
```

Comment: what happens with GET host:9200?

Comment: sorry for the delayed answer. curl -XGET 'http://host:9200' returns:


    "name" : "Xjm....",
    "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
    "cluster_uuid" : "opJyBG6ySV-........",
    "version" : {
      "number" : "6.8.6",
      "build_flavor" : "default",
      "build_type" : "rpm",
      "build_hash" : "3d9.....",
      "build_date" : "2019-12-13T17:",
      "build_snapshot" : false,
      "lucene_version" : "7.7.2",
      "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "5.6.0",
      "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "5.0.0"
    },
    "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"